# How to change image on JLabel dynamically in Java

Tags: java, image, netbeans

I'm working on a java project in which m ask to display the records saved in database(SQL).Its like a simple application which display record of tennis player, when you select his/her name.
I am facing problems while *putting image on Jlabel for respective player selection*.
I just don't know how to solve this problem.
Please provide a working solution if you can, I am not that much expert as java coder so please be linear as much as you can.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to display image into JLabel. if you want to display dynamic data into fram, then you have to create JLabel `JLabel label = new JLabel(imageIcon);` with dynamic name kine using `id` which getting from DB.

```
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setTitle("JLabel Test");
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("yourFile.gif");
JLabel label = new JLabel(imageIcon);

frame.add(label);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I dont think this gonna work, as image should change with the player I choose to view its details. Ex. when I select Sachin , in JLable it should be Sachin not someone other.